# Any good app to manage the blocking of websites?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I'm currently setting up 12.04 for a Windows convert-friend of mine. He has a problem with porn movies and has been trying to manage this problem. He's asked me to block his favourite porn sites to help with his addiction. Are there any available apps to manage the blocking/unblocking of certain websites?

Comment: Maybe [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls)

Answer (score 2):

These days I'd skip local solutions. They're trivial to  circumvent (eg, use a smartphone).

I'd be looking at local network level solutions like changing the DNS to a blocking service like [OpenDNS's family filter](http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls#family) (and change their router password to something they don't know). Not perfect, but better than nothing.

... Or talk to the ISP directly. Many offer network level parental controls.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall in your friend's DSL or cable gateway or in his router may also be able to block on a site-by-site basis for the entire household's local network, and a Linux firewall can block it for his desktop or laptop (the latter blocking it if he is at home or connected away from home). There are many front ends to [iptables](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-linux-firewall/)  which is the actual Linux firewall; here are [reviews for several of them](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-firewalls-697177).

As a simple solution, edit **/etc/hosts** so the top level of the domains y'all concerned with are redirected to 127.0.0.1 and therefore never resolve. http://accs-net.com/hosts/hostsforlinux.html offers an explanation.